# I want to output certain rows froms a spreadsheet to a different file, if they contain a number which is one higher than in the cell above

Tags: csv

I have a large csv file looking a little like this:

```
SomeData,SomeData,1,SomeData  
SomeData,SomeData,1,SomeData  
SomeData,SomeData,2,SomeData  
SomeData,SomeData,3,SomeData  
SomeData,SomeData,1,SomeData  
SomeData,SomeData,1,SomeData  
SomeData,SomeData,1,SomeData  
SomeData,SomeData,1,SomeData  
SomeData,SomeData,2,SomeData  
SomeData,SomeData,3,SomeData  
SomeData,SomeData,4,SomeData  
SomeData,SomeData,5,SomeData  
SomeData,SomeData,1,SomeData  
SomeData,SomeData,1,SomeData  
SomeData,SomeData,1,SomeData  
SomeData,SomeData,1,SomeData
```

I want to create a new csv file which only contains rows where the 3rd value is part of a set i.e. if the value in 3rd field of the line below is one higher, then I want both those lines to be included.

So, in the example above I only want rows 2-4 and 8-12 to be saved in a new file.

I'm struggling to work out how to tell `grep` to look for that pattern.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is in the file `datafile` you can use `awk` for this processing. (You can't use `grep` because it only deals with single lines of context.)

```
awk -F, '
    # Initially we are not in a block
    BEGIN { inblock=0 }

    # If the third field is greater than that on the previous line, print
    # it. But if we were not already in a block then print the saved line
    # too - and mark that we are now in a block
    NR>1 && $3>third { if (!inblock) { print line; inblock=1 } print $0 }

    # If we are in a block and the third field is smaller that the previous
    # line value, drop out of the block
    inblock && $3<=third { inblock=0 }

    # Save the values each time around
    {third=$3; line=$0 }
' datafile
SomeData,SomeData,1,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,2,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,3,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,1,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,2,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,3,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,4,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,5,SomeData
```

Comment: My output includes all 8 lines but it changes the '1' to '2' in lines one and four. So it works for my purposes but I can't see why it changes the third column value from 1 to 2

Comment: @AndrewJennings fixed. I had a copy-paste typo where I'd written `$line` in the `awk` script but should have written `line`. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Kusalananda fixed - see previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

CSV files are tricky.  Working on the assumption that `Somedata` is a properly quoted data field that may contain commas, we may replace the delimiter with something that is definitely not occurring in the data, for example a tab character (`$'\t'` in most modern shells) (you will change this to something you know works).  If the data fields are free from commas, just skip the `csvformat` bits here.

Using [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/):

```
$ csvformat -D$'\t' data.csv
SomeData        SomeData        1       SomeData
SomeData        SomeData        1       SomeData
SomeData        SomeData        2       SomeData
SomeData        SomeData        3       SomeData
SomeData        SomeData        1       SomeData
etc.
```

We can then pass this to an `awk` script that does the actual work of finding the groups.

```
NR > 1 && $3  == count + 1 {
    # This line is part of the set.

    ++count;        # We expect this value on the next line.
    ++set_size;     # This is the number of lines in the set.

    # Output previous line and remember this line.
    print previous_line;
    previous_line = $0;

    # Continue with next line.
    next;
}

set_size > 0 && $3 != count + 1 {
    # This line is not part of the set, but we're currently tracking a
    # set.  This means that the set ended, so output the last line of
    # the set.

    print previous_line;
    set_size = 0;
}

{
    # This line might be part of the next set.

    count = $3;
    previous_line = $0
}
```

Running it:

```
$ csvformat -D$'\t' data.csv | awk -F$'\t' -f script.awk
SomeData        SomeData        1       SomeData
SomeData        SomeData        2       SomeData
SomeData        SomeData        3       SomeData
SomeData        SomeData        1       SomeData
SomeData        SomeData        2       SomeData
SomeData        SomeData        3       SomeData
SomeData        SomeData        4       SomeData
SomeData        SomeData        5       SomeData
```

Then just get it back on standard comma-delimited form:

```
$ csvformat -D$'\t' data.csv | awk -F$'\t' -f script.awk | csvformat -d$'\t'
SomeData,SomeData,1,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,2,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,3,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,1,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,2,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,3,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,4,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,5,SomeData
```

If the data is free of commas inside of the data fields, you may leave `csvformat` out of it completely:

```
$ awk -F',' -f script.awk data.csv
SomeData,SomeData,1,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,2,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,3,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,1,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,2,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,3,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,4,SomeData
SomeData,SomeData,5,SomeData
```